# List items next to each other strangely move out their place

Tags: css

I have a footer with links listed next to each other separated by a dot. (refering to this part ONLY in my JSFIDDLE:

```
            <ul class="footer-titles">
                <li><a href="http://www.example.com/linkn/">ABC</a> •</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.example.com/asdasda/">DEF</a> •</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.example.com/asdasdasd/">GHI</a> •</li>
                <li style="padding: 0;"><a href="http://www.example.com/fghjfgnt/" style="padding-right: 0;">JKL</a></li>
            </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s28nko9t/

so SOMETIMES when refreshing (yes, most of the time it's ok), it looks something like this: 
[image]

The problem is that the last item is jumping to the bottom. Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers or specific one? I cannot get the last link to fall to the next line like in the screenshot above in _Chrome_.

Comment: hmm. I use chrome so i've never seen this part on other pages. 
I'll refresh it in other browsers and tell you in a sec

Comment: What is the size of the window when this happens.  Also if you could modify your fiddle and include what is really required. I see multiple widths assigned to same class which are overwritten. 

The problem itself does not seem reproducible.  When does it happen when you refresh your fiddle?

Comment: I refreshed it 4234234 times on explorer and firefox and nothing like this happened there ( :0 ! ). It should be viewable on all desktop platforms - currently viewing it on 1366px width and 1920px width screens. It doesn't happen on the jsfiddle. i'm almost sure it should be ok.

Comment: No, 99% of my traffic are chrome users :'(

Comment: Give a link of your working website then. Will refresh it there and see.

Comment: send me an email walid.doch@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

Might be that the container of the links has a smaller width than they need to have to be neatly next to each other.

Give the list items a fixed font-size for example 16 pixels.

```
.site-footer .footer-titles {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    float: inherit;
    width: 55%;
    min-width: 240px
}
```

Comment: I tried to make it wider - the list items become un-centered.